# installing open project for docker with extrenal network

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, openproject

I have the following network as reverse proxy on my server

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - dhparam:/etc/nginx/dhparam
      - vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - ./client_max_upload_size.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/client_max_upload_size.conf
      - ./www.domain.com:/etc/nginx/vhost.d/www.domain.com
    labels:
      - "com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy"
    restart: always
    networks:
      - net

  letsencrypt:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    container_name: lets-encrypt-proxy-companion
    depends_on:
      - "nginx-proxy"
    volumes:
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
      - vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    environment:
      DEFAULT_EMAIL:mail@gmail.com
    restart: always
    networks:
      - net

volumes:
  certs:
  html:
  vhost:
  dhparam:


networks:
  net:
    external: true
```

This setup works well and i am able to deploy multiple containers and everything works.

I'm trying to create an open-project container on this server and i wish for it to use the "net" proxy.
I have tried removing the proxy from the 'openproject' compose file and it didn't help

```
version: "3.7"

networks:
  net:
  external: true
  backend:

volumes:
  pgdata:
  opdata:

x-op-restart-policy: &restart_policy
  restart: unless-stopped
x-op-image: &image
  image: openproject/community:${TAG:-12}
x-op-app: &app
  <<: *image
  <<: *restart_policy
  environment:
    RAILS_CACHE_STORE: "memcache"
    OPENPROJECT_CACHE__MEMCACHE__SERVER: "cache:11211"
    OPENPROJECT_RAILS__RELATIVE__URL__ROOT: "${OPENPROJECT_RAILS__RELATIVE__URL__ROOT:-}"
    DATABASE_URL: "${DATABASE_URL:-postgres://postgres:p4ssw0rd@db/openproject?pool=20&encoding=unicode&reconnect=true}"
    RAILS_MIN_THREADS: 4
    RAILS_MAX_THREADS: 16
    # set to true to enable the email receiving feature. See ./docker/cron for more options
    IMAP_ENABLED: "${IMAP_ENABLED:-false}"
  volumes:
    - "${OPDATA:-opdata}:/var/openproject/assets"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:13
    <<: *restart_policy
    stop_grace_period: "3s"
    volumes:
      - "${PGDATA:-pgdata}:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-p4ssw0rd}
      POSTGRES_DB: openproject
    networks:
      - backend

  cache:
    image: memcached
    <<: *restart_policy
    networks:
      - backend

  proxy:
    <<: *image
    <<: *restart_policy
    command: "./docker/prod/proxy"
    ports:
      - "${PORT:-8080}:80"
    environment:
      APP_HOST: web
      OPENPROJECT_RAILS__RELATIVE__URL__ROOT: "${OPENPROJECT_RAILS__RELATIVE__URL__ROOT:-}"
      VIRTUAL_HOST: ${SITE_DOMAIN},www.${SITE_DOMAIN}
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: ${SITE_DOMAIN},www.${SITE_DOMAIN}
    depends_on:
      - web
    networks:
      - net

  web:
    <<: *app
    command: "./docker/prod/web"
    networks:
      - net
      - backend
    depends_on:
      - db
      - cache
      - seeder
    labels:
      - autoheal=true
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8080${OPENPROJECT_RAILS__RELATIVE__URL__ROOT:-}/health_checks/default"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 30s

  autoheal:
    image: willfarrell/autoheal:1.2.0
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    environment:
      AUTOHEAL_CONTAINER_LABEL: autoheal

  worker:
    <<: *app
    command: "./docker/prod/worker"
    networks:
      - backend
    depends_on:
      - db
      - cache
      - seeder

  cron:
    <<: *app
    command: "./docker/prod/cron"
    networks:
      - backend
    depends_on:
      - db
      - cache
      - seeder

  seeder:
    <<: *app
    command: "./docker/prod/seeder"
    restart: on-failure
    networks:
      - backend
```

I have tried defining the network in the compose file, but it doesn't work
any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by removing the ports definition from the proxy service in the OP compose file.
I also increased the max execution time in the reverse proxy.